# C++ multithreading; use of deleted function / invocable of conversion to rvalues

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing an multithreading programing in C++. I'm also new to C++.
I use the SFML library for it.

I want to execute an method in an object in a new thread.

Here's the code I want to execute:

```
// [...]
Protocol user_connection;
std::thread new_con (&Protocol::connect, &user_connection, std::ref(client));
// [...]
```

The Protocol class:

```
class Protocol {

    private:
        sf::TcpSocket client;

    public:
        Protocol() { /* [...] */ }

        static void connect(sf::TcpSocket& client) { /* [...] */}
};
```

But when I try to execute it I get the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/thread: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(sf::TcpSocket&); _Args = {Protocol*, std::reference_wrapper<sf::TcpSocket>}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
main.cpp:59:88:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:136:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
136 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
```

Now I also tried to wrap the `user_connection` into `std::ref()`. But when I do this I get another error which states:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:59:79: error: use of deleted function ‘void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = Protocol*]’
  59 |             std::thread new_con (&Protocol::connect, std::ref(&user_connection), std::ref(client));
     |                                                                               ^
     In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:54,
                      from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:52,
                      from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/memory:84,
                      from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:44,
                      from main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/refwrap.h:375:10: note: declared here
 375 |     void ref(const _Tp&&) = delete;
```

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: static method doesn't take hidden pointer to object, `&user_connection` is not needed here.

Comment: If you have a static method, you shouldn't pass the this-pointer to the thread.

Comment: @rafix07 I tried to remove it but I get an error then

Comment: @JVApen I tried that and it worked straight out of the box. Thanks!

Comment: @JVApen can you create an answer so that I can flag it as correct?

Comment: @burn_stick really ? [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ssasfs)

Comment: please don't edit answers into the question, if you have solved your own problem you can create your own answer

Comment: The answer is added, I've also added some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your example ain't a minimal reproducible example, so I created one on [compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/6rTfs8).

The problem you are having is a mismatch between the arguments you pass via `std::thread` to the function with the arguments the function accepts that is passed.

Let's look at `std::thread new_con (&Protocol::connect, &user_connection, std::ref(client));`, here we see as the first argument a function, all other arguments are the ones used to call that function.

Since the method is defined as static and has a single argument, this doesn't require the implicit this-pointer to be passed. As a result, you only have 1 argument in this function, which mismatch with the 2 arguments.

There are 2 ways of fixing this:

- Remove the static keyword from the method: `void connect(sf::TcpSocket& client) { /* [...] */}` [compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/sMEava)
- Remove the `&user_connection` from the construction of `std::thread`: `std::thread new_con (&Protocol::connect, std::ref(client));` [compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/z6hs6b)

Personally, I always find this confusing, I always use threads with a single lambda: `std::thread new_con([&client](){ Protocol::connect(client); });` [compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fv4G6E). The error messages for this way of using them are better this way.